# Is it possible to pass a machine's hostname as subject of the command `mail` in linux?

Tags: bash, centos6.4

I'm trying to extract some information from a list of servers and so I wrote this one liner which I will then pass through `ssh user@machine 'command'`:

```
# hostname > info ; cat /etc/*-release | awk 'NR==3' >> info ; uname -a >> info ; rpm -qa >> info ; mail -s '`hostname` install list' itaig@mydomain.com < info
```

I've also tried:

```
[root@itai-test ~]# hostname > info ; cat /etc/*-release | awk 'NR==3' >> info ; uname -a >> info ; rpm -qa >> info ;hn=`/bin/hostname` ; mail -s '$hn install list' itaig@amadeus.co.il < info
```

But the subject looks like this:
`$hn install list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes instead of single quotes in your subject:

```
[root@itai-test ~]# hostname > info ; cat /etc/*-release | awk 'NR==3' >> info ; uname -a >> info ; rpm -qa >> info ;hn=`/bin/hostname` ; mail -s "$hn install list" itaig@amadeus.co.il < info
```

Your shell will then interpolate the `$hn` variable in your subject.